# problemas con los css y js en laravel

Tags: javascript, css, laravel

Estoy usando laravel 5.6 e instale el paquete Infyom con la plantilla de AdminLTE, la cuestión es que la referencia a los css y js de esa plantilla son direcciones de internet y funciona bien la vista pero solo en la pc donde lo estoy programando cuando entro al sitio desde otra pc no se ve ningún estilo ni funcionan los scrips creo que es que están guardados en cache en mi pc porque me funcionan incluso sin internet.

La idea es que me he descargado esos css y js para tenerlos locales pero cuando quito la referencia de internet y pongo mi referencia local a los archivos simplemente no funciona.

Esto es un ejemplo de como incluyo las librerías de Select2

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/select2.min.css')}}"> //esto en la parte del css y en la parte de los scripts
<script src="{{asset('js/select2.min.js ')}}"></script>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75436/discussion-on-question-by-luis-dariel-valenciano-problemas-con-los-css-y-js-en-l).

Comment: Votando por cerrar como "error tipográfico" por lo comentado en [este otro chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43759938#43759938)